# Select Query without Tablespace reference

Tags: reference, tablespace

HI

In TOAD when I write

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
```

I get error "table or view does not exist". But when I write

```
SELECT * FROM DEP.EMPLOYEES
```

it works fine. how do I query a table without referencing the tablespace. i know it is definitely possible but I cannot find how.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Oracle, you can alter the session this way: 
`ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT SCHEMA = DEP`

For DB2: 
`SET SCHEMA='DEP'`